# Is the first sentence acceptable in English?

Tags: sentence-construction, attributives

> You are the guy **who we are trying to learn from**.

is the ordinary sentence structure I make when I talk. But I know that the standard English is

> You are the guy **from whom we are trying to learn**.

To be honest, the second one is a bit hard for me. I want to know, is the first acceptable, and could you give me some methods about how to make the standard attributive clause in which a verb-preposition combination exist?

Comment: The former is called a *preposition stranding*, it's perfectly fine, but some purists might dispute you for ending a sentence with a preposition. The latter is called pied-piping, usually preferable in academic writing.

Comment: Preposition fronting (or pied-piping) is generally found in formal English. 'guy' is usually used in informal English. Maybe a more formal word or phrase instead of 'guy' would make your second sentence more likely: 'You are the world-renowned expert from whom we are trying to learn'.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the first sentence acceptable in English?

Yes.  But...

Unless you're trying to be overly formal or respectful, a more common way to express that would be something like:

> You're the guy we're trying to learn from.